# Issue in getting desired output using c# code on VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, console-application

I have predominantly been using Visual Studio as my IDE to write and run C# code. In VS ,pressing f5 or clicking helps in running the program.

I am pretty new to VS Code IDE and i've installed supporting c# extensions. I created a cs file and added below code

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

I've run following command

> dotnet run

on terminal to view the result and it prints as expected "hello world".

but if I change the input inside and run it does not print the given input in the .

I'd like to know ,if there are more methods to run program on VS Code and is it possible to see the results on a console window like visual studio ?

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAHGm.png)

[hello world !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfU4Q.png)

Comment: It looks like you did not save the changes to Program.cs. Press Ctrl + S to save the file and run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not saved the project, if the problem is not fixed I would suggest you to look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67687775/you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-c-should-we-find-a-c-sharp-extension/67820063#67820063)